# What is the code for this simplification (edited: rewrite) using symbolic tool box in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simplify

What is the code for this simplification (edited: rewrite):

> sin^2(t) => (1/2)(1-cos(2t))

using symbolic toolbox in Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

You are not simplifying. You are rewriting the expression in terms of something else. As such, there's no available function to do directly what you want. You may try the `rewrite` function in order to write an expression in terms of another. For example:

```
>> rewrite(sin(t)^2, 'cos')

ans =

1 - cos(t)^2
```

Take into account that the available expressions to rewrite the original expression is limited. Hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried functions like 'rewrite' but no one works for me !